# does elmah send errors to mail even if they got filtered ?

Tags: elmah

I have a web site mvc4 c# using elmah error logging. in my web config I declared email send on error from elmah and error filtering in code in global.asax :

```
void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception.GetBaseException() is InvalidOperationException)
    {
       if (e.Exception.Message.StartsWith("The connection id is in the incorrect format"))
           e.Dismiss();
     }
}
```

when I go to my `http://mydomain/elmah.axd` I see no more errors that got filtered.
but I get them to mail.

i.e - if the application has error ""The connection id is in the incorrect format" ,I get notify on email by elmah, and I don't want to be notify ... is there a way to filter it also in mail notifications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.  You have to define a second function to filter out the Emails separately.  The signature of this function is:

```
void ErrorMail_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Calling e.Dismiss() within this method will prevent the Exception from being e-mailed.

See https://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFiltering